# I can only access the first index[0] of the menu array but I can't access second index[1] between I'm using Context hooks React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, react-context

Here is my Context Code to access the data:

```
const initialState = {
  
    products: restaurantMenu[0].menu,
    cart: [],
  };
 
const reducer = (state = initialState, action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD':
            const item = state.products.find(
                (product) => product.id === action.payload.id
              );
              // Check if Item is in cart already
              const inCart = state.cart.find((item) =>
                item.id === action.payload.id ? true : false
              );
        
              return {
                ...state,
                cart: inCart
                  ? state.cart.map((item) =>
                      item.id === action.payload.id
                        ? { ...item, qty: item.qty + 1 }
                        : item
                    )
                  : [...state.cart, { ...item, qty: 1 }],
              };
            
        case 'DELETE':
        return {
            ...state,
            cart: state.cart.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id),
          };
       
        case 'INCREASE':
               const tempCart = state.cart.map((cartItem) => {
                if (cartItem.id === action.payLoad.id) {
                  return { ...cartItem, qty: cartItem.qty + 1 };
                }
                return cartItem;
              });
              return { ...state, cart: tempCart };
        
        case 'DECREASE':
                const temp = state.cart.map((cartItem) => {
                    if (cartItem.id === action.payLoad.id) {
                      return { ...cartItem, qty: cartItem.qty - 1 };
                    }
                 return cartItem;
                  })
                  .filter((cartItem) => cartItem.qty !== 0);
                return { ...state, cart: temp };
              
        case 'CLEAR':
              return {cart :[]}
           
        default:
            throw new Error(`unknow action.${action.type}`)
    }

}

export const CartProvider =({children})=>{
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer,initialState)
    return(
        <CartDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        <CartStateContext.Provider value={state}>
            {children}
        </CartStateContext.Provider>

        </CartDispatchContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useCart = ()=>useContext(CartStateContext);
export const useDispatch =()=> useContext(CartDispatchContext);
```

here is my Data Code:

```
 export const restaurantMenu = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Western",
            foodType:'Western Food',
            rating: 4.8,
            categories: [1],
            icon: icons.western,
            photo: images.background_1,
            price: 20.00,
            menu:[
            {
               id: 1,
                name: "Chicken Fajita",
                photo: images.Chicken_Fajita,
                description: "Grilled Chicken Breast, Onion, Bell Pepper, Fajita Sauce",
                price: 20.00,
                rating:3,
                reviews:89,

            },
            {
               id: 2,
                name: "Cordon Bleu",
                photo: images.Cordon_Bleu,
                description: "Panne Fried Chicken Breast Stuffed with Mozzarella Cheese, 
                Mushroom",
                price: 21.00,
                rating:4,
                reviews:90,
 
        
            },
          ],

     {
        id: 2,
        name: "Burgers",
        rating: 4.5,
        categories: [2],
        icon: icons.burger,
        photo: images.background_2,
        price: 10.00,
        menu:[
            {
               id: 3,
                name: "Beef Burger",
                photo: images.Beef_Burger,
                description: "Fresh Beef Patty, Lettuce, Mayonnaise Topped with Cheddar Cheese",
                price: 15.00,
                rating:3,
                reviews:89,

            },
            {
               id: 4,
                name: "Chicken Burger",
                photo: images.Chicken_Burger,
                description: "Fresh Chicken Burger Patty, Lettuce, Garlic Sauce, Cocktail Sauce,",
                price: 15.00,
                rating:3,
                reviews:89,
            },
      ]       
  ]
```

I'm trying to access all menus arrays but I only can access the first index[0] of first menu but I can't access the second I know because I put in my code [0] which the first menu but how I can edit the code to the right way to access all menu arrays.

Comment: If you only care about the menu not other fields (price, photo etc.), you can just do `products: restaurantMenu.flatMap(({ menu }) => menu),`

Comment: Actually, I do care about all fields inside the menu(price, rating et.). so how I can do that?

Comment: How is `restaurantMenu` going to be used?  It seems that the posted `context` code is mostly about handling `cart`.

Comment: how can access the menu fields of first object and second menu of second object. I only can access the first object menu index[0] and I can do calculate to the price but when i select the second menu it shows is up but i can't calculate he price is giving me Nan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is just iterate through every object and just pick out the `menu` key.

```
const initialState = {
    products: restaurantMenu.reduce((acc, item) => {
        acc.push(...item.menu);
        return acc;}, []),
    cart: [],
};
```